# Convert text certificate to crt file

Tags: openssl, certificate, csr

I sent the .CSR file to my client, and they send me the final certificate in text code (copy paste into the mail). Can I convert this code into file .CRT ?

The code is OK, I have tested in: https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just paste the certificate text into a plain-text file and give it `.crt` extension.